# How to parse String to java.sql.date

Tags: java, date, sql-date-functions

I have a String

```
String s = "01 NOVEMBER 2012";
```

Then I want parse it to sqlDate. And insert it into the database.

Is it possible to parse that string to sqlDate?!?!

Yup, sql date format is "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: While in 2012 when the question was asked, `java.sql.Date` was the class we used for transferring a date without time of day to and from SQL databases, today it’s better to use `LocalDate` from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse String date to java.util.Date

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse("01 NOVEMBER 2012");
```

and then convert it to java.sql.Date using millis

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Use `java.sql.Date.valueOf()`! It's better.

Comment: java.sql.Date.valueOf() works for JDBC date escape format. The format is "yyyy-[m]m-[d]d" It won't work with every date format.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I am providing the modern answer. I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = 
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd MMMM uuuu")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    String s = "01 NOVEMBER 2012";
    
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(s, dateFormatter);
    
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

> 2012-11-01

You asked for a `java.sql.Date`? By all likelihood you don’t need any. I assume that you wanted one for use with your SQL database. Since JDBC 4.2 you can use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) there too. For example:

```
    PreparedStatement statement = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "insert into your_table (your_date_column) values (?);");
    statement.setObject(1, date);
    statement.executeUpdate();
```

Note the use of `PreparedStatement.setObject()` (not `setDate()`).

If you do need a `java.sql.Date` for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time, the conversion is easy and straightforward:

```
    java.sql.Date oldfashionedJavaSqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedJavaSqlDate);
```

> 2012-11-01

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Related question: [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Jigar Joshi answer.

This code has been able to handle whatever I've needed.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Date date1;
Date date2;
Date date3;

    //converting string into sql date);
    try {
         date1 = new java.sql.Date(
                     ((java.util.Date) new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse("01 NOVEMBER 2012")).getTime());

        date2 = new java.sql.Date(
                    ((java.util.Date)newSimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("02/09/2012")).getTime());

        date3 = new java.sql.Date(
                    ((java.util.Date) new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse("03092012")).getTime());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    System.out.println("sqlDate test1:" + date1);
    System.out.println("sqlDate test2:" + date2);
    System.out.println("sqlDate test3:" + date3);


    output:
           sqlDate test1:2012-11-01
           sqlDate test2:2012-09-02
           sqlDate test3:2012-09-03
```