# Unable to setDate in prepareStatement in Java

Tags: java, mysql

If I change

`ps.setString(3, ((JTextField)txtDateRecv.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());`

to

`ps.setDate(3, ((JTextField)txtDateRecv.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());` then I get an error message showing in Netbeans IDE 7.2.1

mySQL database field has the column set to 'DATE'.

can someone help me understand where is the issue?

Thanks for the help. Part of the code is as follows;

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            String sql="insert into inventory(DNO,TITLE,RDATE,COPIES) values(?,?,?,?)";
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, txtDvdNo.getText());
            ps.setString(2, txtMovTitle.getText());
            ps.setString(3, ((JTextField)txtDateRecv.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            ps.setString(4, txtCopies.getText());
            ps.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(txtCopies, "New Record added");
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Inventory.this, e.getMessage());
        }
        showInventoryTable();
    }
```

Comment: cast your date into java.sql.date

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844006/).

Comment: `setData()` expects a `java.sql.Date` but you are passing a `java.lang.String`. Of course the Java compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the textual representation of date in JTextField

```
   java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(your_date_format).parse(((JTextField)txtDateRecv.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

then make a java.sql.Date of it and set it to PreparedStatement

```
   ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```